# troubleshooting a NullPointerException in grails

Tags: grails

preface note: I'm just starting to learn Grails, so I'm sure there are many other problems and room for optimization.

I've got two domains, a parent (Collection) and child (Event), in a one-to-many mapping.  I'm trying to code an integration test for the deletion of children.  Prior to the code in question, I've successfully created a parent and three children.  The point where I'm having problems is *getting* a single child in preparation to delete it.  The first line of my sample code is only there because of my rudimentary attempt to troubleshoot.

```
// lines 95-100 of my EventIntegrationTests.groovy file
// delete a single event
assertEquals("2nd Event", event2.title)     // passes
def foundEvent = Event.get(event2.id)       // no apparent problems
assertEquals("2nd Event", foundEvent.title) // FAILS (line #98)
foundEvent.delete()
assertFalse Event.exists(foundEvent.id)
```

The error message I'm getting is:

```
 Cannot get property 'title' on null object 

 java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot get property 'title' on null object
         at edu.learninggrails.EventIntegrationTests.testEventsDelete(EventIntegrationTests.groovy:98)
```

What should my next troubleshooting steps be?  (Since the first assertEquals passes, event2 is clearly not null, so at this point I have no idea how to troubleshoot the failure of the second assertEquals.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not evident from the code: did you persist event2 by calling `save()`? Get will try to retrieve it from the persistent storage (the in-memory database for example) and if the event wasn't saved, the retrieved instance will be null.

If you did save it, did the save go through OK? Calling `event.save()` will return false if there was something wrong while saving the item (like a validation error). Lastly, you might try calling `event.save(flush:true)` in case the Hibernate session doesn't handle this case as you might expect (I'm not entirely sure about this one, but it can't hurt to try).

Comment: I'm trying to build my own learning app as I make my way through Smith & Ledbrook's "Grails in Action" (2009).  In their code and subsequent explanation for 1:m relationships, they indicate that a child instance is persisted simply by adding it to the parent (pp. 83 & 84), so I had not attempted to explicitly 'save()'.  I've tried several different iterations of 'event2.save()' and 'event.save(flush:true)'.  Early on I don't think I was running 'clean' as consistently and frequently as I should have been, so I was getting inconsistent results.

Comment: At this point, my code for that section is:
      // delete a single event
      assertEquals("A '10 2nd Event", event2.title)
      event2.save(flush:true)
      event2.id.inspect()
      def foundEvent = Event.get(event2.id)
      foundEvent.inspect()
      assertEquals("A '10 2nd Event", foundEvent.title)
      foundEvent.delete()
      assertFalse Event.exists(foundEvent.id)

Comment: (lack of line breaks in comments is saddening!)

Comment: It is now failing on the last line with an error starting off:
deleted object would be re-saved by cascade (remove deleted object from associations)  

So with the event2.save(flush:true) I appear to be past the problem that brought me here.  At this point, I don't know if it's worthwhile to learn how to test the deletion of a child (Smith & Ledbrook don't cover it), to move on to m:m relationships, or to spend more time to learn about 'flush'.  Regardless, thank you for helping me make it over that hump!

Comment: I don't have that book and in general I always try to save() stuff explicitly, but it is probable that the child instance would've been saved and you only have to save explicitly because you need to flush that save at once. As for the recent error you seem to be getting, if your event is a member of, say, `EventCollection` with a property of `events`, you could try calling `eventCollection.removeFromEvents(event2);`

Comment: In trying to deal with the latest errors (I was able to get removeFromEvents to work, but then working with 'collection' became buggy) I found http://blog.springsource.com/2010/06/23/gorm-gotchas-part-1/ , .../2010/07/02/gorm-gotchas-part-2/ , and .../2010/07/28/gorm-gotchas-part-3/ .  I skimmed enough of part 2 to think it's going to provide the background & guidance that I need. I'm going to read them indepth to see if I can get a good grasp of domain relationships, particularly saving & cascading. Your assistance was critical in recognizing that my 1:m understanding is lacking. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try to print or inspect the event2.id on line 97 and check if you actually have an id, if so check if you actually get an Event object on line 97.

Comment: I don't yet have controllers for these domains, so I'm not sure how I could easily print.  I did try adding both an 'event2.inspect()' and an event2.id.inspect' but I wasn't able to find where they were logged.  I also tried adding a Netbeans breakpoint on the 'inspect' line, but again, I was unable to find the variable's value.  In trying to figure out how to use 'inspect' I also ran across mentions of log4j and I tried to figure that out, but it looked like it was a substantial undertaking.  Since I'm still trying to learn the rudimentary stuff I decided to hold off.  Am I missing something?

Comment: When you are println-ing something (or in integration tests I suppose you could use log4j as well), you can check the println output in the test results (they are in the `target/test-reports` folder).

Comment: <happy dancing> Thank You! Knowing this is sure to make troubleshooting easier!</happy dancing>

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you saved the parent and its children successfully.  after you save, you should make sure that every object that was persisted has a non null id, in your test.

What you are seeing is you created the event2 with a title, but didnt save it.  It passes the first assertion because you created it.  When you do the get, null is returned because your save failed.

in general for DAO integration tests i do the following

1. Setup -- create all objects Ill use in the test.
2. Save -- assert that all ids on saved objects are NOT null.
3. Clear the hibernate session -- this is important because if you don't do it, objects can be in the session from the previous operations.  In your real world scenario, you are probably going to start with a find, i.e. an empty session.  In other words, you are not going to start with anything in the session.  If you are you need to adjust this rule so that the session in the test, when you start the actual testing part, is the same as the session of the code in the wild
4. Load the objects on which you want to operate and do what you need to do.

Comment: See my comments to Gregor about why I hadn't been explicitly saving.  At this point, having just an explicit 'event2.save' doesn't appear to help, but having 'event2.save(flush:true)' does.  I'm still trying to wrap my head around that logic.